# Loop code how to write a while loop for this

Tags: python, while-loop

What is the best way to code the problem below and how to write it?

for every -A- one point
for every Ab - two points

my_pkg = 'AbcdAklpA'

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: can they overlap? for example: Ab contains an A, so the first two characters equal 3 points.

Comment: Yes you can I believe

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do so:

```
points = 0
my_pkg = 'AbcdAklpA'
for i in range(len(my_pkg)):
    if my_pkg[i:i+2] == "Ab":
        points += 2
    if my_pkg[i:i+1] == "A":
        points += 1
print(points)  # 5
```

Comment: Thx but wouldn’t  while loop be better?

Comment: We know the size of the string, I don't see why using a while loop would be any better than using a for loop.